# update json data in sqlite3

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I have this table:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"customers":[{"name": "test1","number": 1111},{"name": "test2","number": 2222}],"enableCheck": true} |

And my new values:

```
$new_customer_name = "test3";
$new_customer_number = "3333";
```

I need a query to add this new values to the data column, I want this:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"custumers":[{"name": "test1","number": 1111},{"name": "test2","number": 2222},{"name": "test3","number": 3333}],"enableCheck": true} |

I try to use select query and edit json and update data but i need a query to update JSON directly into JSON of data

Comment: UPDATE table_name
SET data = JSON_SET(data, '$.customers', JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(data->'$.customers', '{"name": $new_customer_name, "number": $new_customer_number}'))
WHERE id = 1;

Comment: not working in demo sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

I found this and work:

```
UPDATE inbunds SET data = JSON_INSERT(data, '$.customers[2]', json('{"name": $new_customer_name,"number": $new_customer_number}')) WHERE id = 1
```

But now i need count JSON/s in $.customers and add JSON/s into end of $.customers

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question about it instead...it won't get any attention if you bury it in an answer!